# Given $G$ is a group and $a,b\in G $ and $ab=ba$. Prove......

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

1. $ab^n= b^na\;\; \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$
   I have been able to prove this for $n=0$ and for a positive integer (using induction).
   But for $n$a negative integer, I'm not able to prove it:
   $n=-m$ for some positive integer $m$. Starting with the right side, I have
   $ab^n= a(b^{-1})^{m}$. I do not know how to proceed
2. $ (ab)^{n}=a^{n}b^{n}\;\; \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$
   When I'm proving for $n=$ a positive integer using method of induction,
   for $n=k+1$
   $(ab)^{k+1}=(ab)^{k}(ab)= (a^kb^k)(ab)=(a^kb^k)(ba)= a^k(b^k(ba))+ a^k((b^kb)a)= a^k((b^{k+1})a)$.
   How can I continue? I cannot swap the position of $a$.

Comment: You need only consider the case $n = -1$ additionally to the non-negative cases. So, how can you show that $ab^{-1} = b^{-1}a$, given $ab = ba$?

Comment: Another hint: try first to show that $b^{-1}$ commutes with $a^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, @DanielFisher already gave the answer in his comment. So you first prove that $ab^{-1} = b^{-1}a$, then you use induction to show that $ab^{-m} = b^{-m}a$ for all $n\geq 0$. That is, for $m=0$ this is clearly true. Say that it is true for $m=k$ and consider $$ab^{-(k+1)} = ab^{-k}b^{-1} = b^{-k}ab^{-1} = b^{-k}b^{-1}a = b^{-(k+1)}a.$$

That is, you are still going from $k$ to $k+1$.

For the second question for the last step, just use what you have from question 1. Question 1 says exactly that $b^{k+1}a = ab^{k+1}.$

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer and editing

Comment: @JOEF: Glad to help.

Comment: ok,for the second question,it is not necessary to use induction to prove for n=-ve integer?

Comment: @JOEF: I would also do it for negative numbers. So again, you start with $(ab)^{-1} = a^{-1}b^{-1}$ and then prove that $(ab)^{-m} = a^{-m}b^{-m}$ for $m\geq 0$ by induction.

Comment: @JOEF: Let me add a bit more detail.